# Error TFS203082 The checksum value of the file that you uploaded does not match the provided value

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017

I used to work on computer 1, VS2017 and TFS. I had to migrate to computer 2. I got the source code on this computer #2, made one change and tried to commit. I get the error mentioned in the title of this post. Any idea how to resolve it? Thanks

Comment: Can you try the solution mentioned in [this ticket](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ef8e7467-9447-48fb-b978-39952802df7b/a-problem-when-i-check-in-sorcecode-tfs-error-code-is-tf203082?forum=tfsgeneral)?  Its the same error code  TF203082.

Comment: By the way, can you share more details about how you got the source code on this computer #2?